# How to find the right libnvinfer version for Cuda

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, dockerfile

I am building a Docker image, for deep learning:

```
cuda:11.2.0-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu20.04
PYTHON_VERSION=3.7.9
```

For this task I need 3 dependencies to install, but I can't find the right version. The error I get, when building the Docker image:

> E: Version '8.1.1.33-1+cuda11.2' for 'libnvinfer8' was not found E:
> Version '8.1.1.33-1+cuda11.2' for 'libnvinfer-dev' was not found E:
> Version '8.1.1.33-1+cuda11.2' for 'libnvinfer-plugin8' was not found

I was experimenting with other versions as well, but I had no success, so the question is: where/how can I find the right versions which works with cuda 11.2 and ubuntu 20.04. Is there a rule of thumb?

Comment: Share the Dockerfile

Comment: Follow the Nvidia [docker container documention](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker) to install right version of CUDA and cuDNN. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To check which version of TensorRT your `tensorflow` installation expects:

```
>>> import tensorflow
>>> tensorflow.__version__
'2.8.0'
>>> from tensorflow.python.compiler.tensorrt import trt_convert as trt
>>> trt.trt_utils._pywrap_py_utils.get_linked_tensorrt_version()
(7, 2, 2)
>>> trt.trt_utils._pywrap_py_utils.get_loaded_tensorrt_version()
2022-03-24 08:59:15.415733: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64
```

The last command shows that indeed `libnvinfer.so` is missing on your system (you can also check this fact using `ldconfig -p | grep libnv`).

To install it (adapted from Tensorflow's [`gpu.Dockerfile`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.8.0/tensorflow/tools/dockerfiles/dockerfiles/gpu.Dockerfile#L61-L70)), take the TensorRT version in your output from above, double check it's available for your CUDA version on the [nvidia repository](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/), and install:

```
export LIBNVINFER=7.2.2 LIBNVINFER_MAJOR_VERSION=7 CUDA_VERSION=11.0
apt-get install -y libnvinfer${LIBNVINFER_MAJOR_VERSION}=${LIBNVINFER}-1+${CUDA_VERSION} libnvinfer-plugin${LIBNVINFER_MAJOR_VERSION}=${LIBNVINFER}-1+${CUDA_VERSION}
```

The last Python command above should now start working. If you get a similar error again, double check that the so file locations (check with `ldconfig -p | grep libnv`) are included in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Also double check your CUDA version. In my case, I was running the `docker.io/nvidia/cuda:11.5.1-cudnn8-runtime-ubuntu20.04` image, which already contains the [math libraries](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpu-accelerated-libraries) and specifically `libnvrtc.so.11.2` (so for a newer CUDA version than TensorRT supports on the nvidia repository). This becomes evident after running the `apt-get` command above, which gave this output:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnvinfer7 : Depends: cuda-nvrtc-11-0 but it is not going to be installed
```

Answer (score 2):

When doubt:
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu

This was actually the answer and it works like a charm.. follow the official site for **Tested build configurations**

- tensorflow-2.5.0
- cuda:11.2.0
- PYTHON_VERSION=3.8.11
- libcudnn8=8.1.1.33-1+cuda11.2
- libcudnn8-dev=8.1.1.33-1+cuda11.2

Comment: And may I ask where did you find the exact version 8.1.1.33 since one the site I can only detect cuDNN 8.1?

Comment: I see a lot has changed since then on Nvidia's site, they keep these docker files up to date. If you build this docker image: https://hub.docker.com/layers/nvidia/cuda/11.2.0-devel-ubuntu20.04/images/sha256-21bc1bedcf8d2c2d643156fa7b8e3b29e19e85a22a75ecf3a8a3ff263cae7364?context=explore
it should work just fine (with the above setup). Also you could find something similar on the Docker HUB. I found that specific version in one of these configs... apparently since then, other minor versions appeared.