# Tensorflow Could not load dynamic library Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, cudnn, tensorrt

I want to use gpu in my tensorflow training, but it is a disaster.
I've already install cuda cudnn package, and reinstall my gpu driver

Enviroment:

1. pipenv
2. python3.8.10
3. tensorflow==2.10.0, tensorflow-gpu==2.10.0
4. CUDA Version: 11.8
5. NVIDIA-SMI 520.61.05    Driver Version: 520.61.05
6. Ubuntu 20.04

Reproduce:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

Error message:

```
Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.7'
Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.7'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.6'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60368298/could-not-load-dynamic-library-libnvinfer-so-6)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68450867/681865

Comment: @Lescurel I read this but not really helping.
I tried the command in there and met trouble when installing TensorRT
SO I tried other ways to install it but still failed.

Comment: As per this [tested build configuration](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu), Please try again by installing CUDA 11.2 for the tensorflow version 2.10 and verify with this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#linux) that you have fulfilled all the hardware and software requirement to enable GPU support in your system. Let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you.